# aws - can I configure ip allow rules for a specific endpoint

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

My Config is a single EC2 instance.
I'm new to aws and inherited this architecture.
We want to create an endpoint that will be accessible only from the office (specific IP).

What is the best way to achieve that?

is there a vpc / security group rule that will block a certain endpoint regex?

for example

```
    allow traffic to */sensative_endpoint/* only from 84.100.*.*
    for all rest of the endpoints - allow from all ips
```

thanks.

Comment: You would typically do this within the web server configuration on the instance. Nginx / Apache are the most common web servers used.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments this is probably best solved on the web server running on the ec2 instance.

If you are looking for a managed solution you should check [AWS WAF - Web Application Firewall](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/). `WAF` checks every request for the `path` and a bunch of other parameters and allows to define block and allow rules based on those request parameters. If you are running just a single ec2 instance this is however probably overkill.

You cannot solve this just using security groups as those operate at lower OSI layers and don't take the path (to the sensitive endpoint) into account.

Comment: thanks. if the security groups don't take the path into account, how can block all ips (except some) to some paths and allow all ips to the rest of paths?

Comment: you cannot do that with security groups

Comment: so WAF is required for my need in this case ( if I don't want to handle with apache or nginx)